Galois connections for contexts
I am reading Introduction to Lattices and Order, Second Edition by Davey and Priestly.
On page 158, it says that

It can be verified that, for $R\in \mathcal{R}$ and $T\in \mathcal{T}$,
$$R\subset R_{T} \Longleftrightarrow wp_{R} \Lleftarrow T.$$
Thus there is a Galois connection between $\langle \mathcal{R};\subset\rangle$ and $\langle \mathcal{T};\Rrightarrow\rangle^{\partial}$.

Here $\mathcal{T}=(\mathbb{P}(M)\to \mathbb{P}(G))$ is the set of predicate transformers having the form $wp_{R}$ for some $R\in \mathcal{R}$ and $\mathbb{P}(G)$ is the set of predicates on $G$ and it is identified with $\mathcal{P}(G)$. And $R\in\mathcal{R}=\mathcal{P}(G\times M)$ models a program $P$ that terminates. For $T\in\mathcal{T}$,
$$xR_{T}y \Longleftrightarrow (\forall Y\in\mathcal{P}(M))x\in T(Y)\Rightarrow y\in Y.$$
For $Y\subset M$, $wp_{R}(Y)$ is the set of input states $x$ such that $P$ is guaranteed to terminate in a state in $Y$ when it is started from $x$.
What is the order $\Rrightarrow$? And how do we verify $R\subset R_{T} \Longleftrightarrow wp_{R} \Lleftarrow T$?
Edit: I added $P$ terminates, $\mathcal{T}$ is the set of predicate transformers.
Edit 2: I think I figured out. I think $S\Rrightarrow T$ means for any $Y\subset M$, $S(Y)\subset T(Y)$. And for each $T\in\mathcal{T}$, $T=wp_{R}$ for some $R\in\mathcal{R}$.
